# Transfer coordinates to a new system

Tags: image, math, opencv, line, coordinate-systems

I would like to convert a point coordinates to a new generated coordinate system 
the original system start in the top left corner of the image (0,0)

The information that I have in a new system are : 
1- I have the value of the new original (x0,y0) in some where in the image 
2- also I have 2 points on both new axes ( 4 points in total 2 in each line) 
   using this I can calculate the line equation for the 2 lines of axes (y=a1x+b1) ,(y=a2x+b2)
3- I have vector for each line (Vx, Vy)

Note: sometime the new axes rotate (the lines are not exactly horizontal or vertical)

How can I convert the points coordinates to this new system

any help will be so appreciated

here is the image

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ByDR7Vq.png]

Comment: I would like to upload image to describe what I mean , but I cannot because I do not have enough points in this website that allow me to upload !!! ... do you know how can I upload it ?

Comment: Go to http://imgur.com/ and upload your image and edit the post with the link. I will embed the picture in a later edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First express your lines like `a1*(x-x0)+b1*(y-y0)=0` and `a2*(x-x0)+b2*(y-y0)=0` and their intersection `x0`,`y0` is accounted for already in the equations.

**updated signs**

The transformation from `x`,`y` to `z`,`w` is

> ```
> z = -sqrt(a1^2+b1^2)*(a2*(x-x0)+b2*(y-y0))/(a2*b1-a1*b2)
> w =  sqrt(a2^2+b2^2)*(a1*(x-x0)+b1*(y-y0))/(a1*b2-a2*b1)
> ```

and the inverse

> ```
> x = x0 - b1*z/sqrt(a1^2+b1^2) + b2*w/sqrt(a2^2+b2^2)
> y = y0 + a1*z/sqrt(a1^2+b1^2) - a2*w/sqrt(a2^2+b2^2)
> ```

It would be helpful to scale the coefficients such that `sqrt(a1^2+b1^2)=1` and `sqrt(a2^2+b2^2)=1`.

Note that this works for non-orthogonal lines also. As long as they are not parallel and `a2*b1-a1*b2!=0` it is going to work.

***Example***

The `z` line  `(-2)*(x-3) + (1)*(y-1) = 0` and `w` line `(-1)*(x-3) + (-4)*(y-1) = 0` meet at `(3,1)`. The coefficients are thus `a1=-2`, `b1=1`, `a2=-1`, `b2=-4`.

The coordinates `(x,y)=(2,1)` transform to

```
z = -sqrt((-2)^2+1^2) ((-1) (x-3)+(-4) (y-1))/((-1) 1-(-2) (-4)) = 0.2484
w = sqrt((-1)^2+(-4)^2) ((-2) (x-3)+1 (y-1))/((-2) (-4)-(-1) 1) = 0.9162
```

With the inverse

```
x = -1 z/sqrt((-2)^2+1^2)+(-4) w/sqrt((-1)^2+(-4)^2)+3 = 2
y = (-2) z/sqrt((-2)^2+1^2)-(-1) w/sqrt((-1)^2+(-4)^2)+1 = 1
```

**Development**

For a line `a1*(x-x0)+b1*(y-y0)=0` the direction vector along the line is `e1 = [e1x,e1y]= [-b1/sqrt(a1^2+b1^2),a1/sqrt(a1^2+b1^2)]`. Similarly for the other line.

The screen coordinates of a local point `[z,w]` is found by starting at the origin `x0`, `y0` and moving by `z` along the first line and then by `w` along the second line. So

```
x = x0 + e1x*z + e2x*w = x0 -b1/sqrt(a1^2+b1^2)*z - b2/sqrt(a2^2+b2^2)*w
y = y0 + e1y*z + e2y*w = y0 +a1/sqrt(a1^2+b1^2)*z + a2/sqrt(a2^2+b2^2)*w
```

Now I need to flip the direction of the second line to make it work per the original posting visualization, by reversing the sign of `w`.

To find `z`, `w` from `x`, `y` invert the above two equations.

Comment: I see (x0,y0) is the new origin  how about the (x,y), do you mean the coordinates for green point?

Comment: I am little bit confuse mestar, you want to express the line like a1*(x-x0)+b1*(y-y0)=0 and a2*(x-x0)+b2*(y-y0)=0 (what do you mean by this, how can I subtract the origin from the unknown in the equation), In addition , you attach b with y , how about the third term c for example , ax+by+c=0

Comment: The equation `a1*(x-x0)+b1*(y-y0)=0`, represents a line if `a1`, `b1`, `x0`, `y0` are known. If your lines are defined by two points with coordinates `(p1x,p1y)` and `(q1x,q1y)` then `a1=(p1y-q1y)/d` and `b1=(q1x-p1x)/d` with `d=sqrt((p1x-q1x)^2+(p1y-q1y)^2)`.

Comment: `a*x+b*x+c=0` passes through `(x0,y0)` when `c=-a*x0-b*y0` such that `a*x+b*x+(-a*x0-b*y0)=0` or `a*(x-x0)+b*(y-y0)=0`.

Comment: I appreciate your answer :D
I will put some effort to understand this

Comment: This formula give me the output negative output point , I would like to get positive points , how can I change the sign ?

Comment: Try inverting the sign of `z` in the calculations above.

Comment: Hi mester , I got this output when I apply your suggestion solution 
 points in Z line (325,25),(373,422) , points in W line (154,280),(552,232) , origin (353,256)
 current point = (299,228) , transfer to = (34,-50) 
there is a problem with sign
I draw new photo to explain more what is the sign that I am looking  
http://i.imgur.com/we48K1r.png

Comment: can you sir explain how you got this formula to calculate x,w ?

Comment: Dude, just flip the sign for `w` wherever you use it. This is a product of which is the direction of the lines.

Comment: I appreciate your patient   :*)