# transfer the co-ordinates error in function

Tags: math, opencv, line, coordinate-systems

I am trying to transfer the coordinates of the points to a new generated system coordinates

the original points in the original system is in the top left corner ....

I wrote the following function to transfer the coordinates
I am using the formal that I got from this question 
[pre_question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956033/transfer-coordinates-to-a-new-system)
this question has 2 photos that show what I mean and the sign for each part

The problem now is , I am getting negative value for w ! 
can anyone please check this function and let me know where is the problem

Thanks

{

```
CvPoint transfer_coordinate (CvPoint pt1 , CvPoint pt2 , CvPoint pt3 , CvPoint pt4 , CvPoint origin , CvPoint current)
{
// pt1 , pt2 ==> points in line Z 
// pt3 , pt4 ==> points in line W 
double a1 , a2 , b1 , b2 , d1 , d2;

d1= sqrt(pow((pt1.x - pt2.x),2.0)+ pow((pt1.y - pt2.y),2.0)); 
d2= sqrt(pow((pt3.x - pt4.x),2.0)+ pow((pt3.y - pt4.y),2.0)); 

a1 =(pt1.y-pt2.y)/d1;
b1 =(pt2.x-pt1.x)/d1;

a2 =(pt3.y-pt4.y)/d2; 
b2 =(pt4.x-pt3.x)/d2; 

CvPoint new_point;
//z = -sqrt(a1^2+b1^2)*(a2*(x-x0)+b2*(y-y0))/(a2*b1-a1*b2)
//w =  sqrt(a2^2+b2^2)*(a1*(x-x0)+b1*(y-y0))/(a1*b2-a2*b1)
//z
new_point.x = -round(sqrt(pow(a1,2.0)+ pow(b1,2.0)) * (a2 * (current.x - origin.x) + b2 * (current.y - origin.y))/(a2 * b1 - a1 * b2));
// w
new_point.y = round(sqrt(pow(a2,2.0)+ pow(b2,2.0)) * (a1 * (current.x - origin.x) + b1 * (current.y - origin.y))/(a1 * b2 - a2 * b1)); 

CvPoint reverse_point; 
//x = x0 - b1*z/sqrt(a1^2+b1^2) + b2*w/sqrt(a2^2+b2^2)
//y = y0 + a1*z/sqrt(a1^2+b1^2) - a2*w/sqrt(a2^2+b2^2)
//x
reverse_point.x = round (origin.x - b1 * new_point.x / sqrt(pow(a1,2.0) + pow(b1,2.0)) + b2 * new_point.y /sqrt(pow(a2,2)+ pow(b2,2)));
//y
reverse_point.y = round (origin.y + a1 * new_point.x / sqrt(pow(a1,2.0) + pow(b1,2.0)) - a2 * new_point.y /sqrt(pow(a2,2)+ pow(b2,2)));

//printf("\n points in Z line (%d,%d),(%d,%d) , points in W line (%d,%d),(%d,%d) , origin (%d,%d)",pt1.x,pt1.y,pt2.x,pt2.y,pt3.x,pt3.y,pt4.x,pt4.y,origin.x,origin.y);
//printf("\n current point = (%d,%d) , new point = (%d,%d) , reverse point = (%d,%d)" , current.x,current.y,new_point.x,new_point.y,reverse_point.x,reverse_point.y);

return new_point ;
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

If your W-axis corresponds to X-axis, then affine transformation matrix is M = [R]*[T], where R is rotation matrix by Phi angle and T is translation matrix by x0, y0

```
R = Cos(phi) -Sin(phi) 0
    Sin(phi)  Cos(phi) 0
    0         0       1
```

and

```
T = 1  0  0
    0  1  0
    dx dy 1
```

You have to multiply these matrices to get M matrix and get inverse matrix MR = Inverse(M). Then you can use M and MR to transform coordinates from XY to WZ system and vice versa
[xnew, ynew, 1] = [xold, yold, 1] * [M]

[More information here](http://cs.iupui.edu/~sfang/cs550/cs550-note3.pdf)